Having a problem uploading image to Stock Items via REST API
I'm trying to use the REST API to upload an image file to the Stock Items record, where the image is provided from an https URL. I'm using this PUT call (on my local dev instance):
http://localhost/Acumatica/entity/Default/23.200.001/StockItem/010005/Files/https://client.blob.core.windows.net/sitedocs/imagegallery/lineart/a-sample-image-1.jpg

I get the following error:
[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).]

How can I get around this?  Can I not obtain an image from an https URL as I'm trying to do?
What would be a good alternative?
Thanks much...

As far as I remember you are supposed to bass the image bytes (data) as the body of the request and not a link to the image

How would you convert that in a simple REST call?  Seems more like C#...

Where from are you sending the request? For example, Postman has an option to send binary files https://ibb.co/P684xwB

I used these as examples (even though the second one uses a different key field.  They don't seem to require anything but the actual file:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011795/acumatica-api-appointment-attachments   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469155/how-to-attach-file-to-email-using-rest-api

In both cases, the REST API requires the file to be sent as a binary "body" to the request. It is actually in the screenshot of the Postmain in this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011795/acumatica-api-appointment-attachments

so...how would you do that outside of Postman?....  any C# examples?

just added an example as an answer

Here is an example how to attach a file to the Stock Item record.
var client = new RestClient("BASE_URL");//https://localhost

//Login into the system
var loginRequest = new RestRequest("/Acumatica/entity/auth/login", Method.Post);
loginRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var body = @"{" + "\n" +
    @"  ""name"" : ""USERNAME""," + "\n" +
    @"  ""password"": ""PASSWORD""" + "\n" +
@"}";
loginRequest.AddStringBody(body, DataFormat.Json);
RestResponse response = client.Execute(loginRequest);

//Read the file as a byte[]
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\USER\\Downloads\\test.jpg");
//Create a PUT request using the ID of the Item and the name of the file.
var attachFileRequest = new RestRequest("/Acumatica/entity/Default/23.200.001/files/PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemMaint/Item/2ea2f35a-072f-ed11-835b-1293d93768b3/test.jpg", Method.Put);
attachFileRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
attachFileRequest.AddBody(fileData, "application/octet-stream");
var response2 = client.Execute(attachFileRequest);

//Logout from the system
var logoutRequest = new RestRequest("/Acumatica/entity/auth/logout", Method.Post);
logoutRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
logoutRequest.AddStringBody(body, DataFormat.Json);
RestResponse response3 = client.Execute(logoutRequest);


Thanks for that, Samvel - one question:  Which NuGet packages do I need for RestRequest?  I tried the RestSharp package - but once that was installed I got another error for a missing reference of different package, which, once I installed that package, led to multiple errors...

@pmfith In my case I was simply referencing the RestSharp and System.Text.Json from Acumatica's Bin folder, but I believe you can use the Nuget packages for these 2 libraries as well https://ibb.co/VNpGt9B

That did it - thanks much (once again), Samvel!  ;D
